# Android, confirmation message user style whatsapp

Tags: android, sms-gateway

I'm looking for a **SMS** sending service which I can use to send a confirmation message to an app, Whatsapp style.

I found some interesting things, but never worked with a scenario like this, and find it interesting to hear tips from someone who has already done something similar.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291196/android-as-an-sms-gateway-for-integration-with-web-application

I'm using [Parse](https://parse.com/) to my backend app, Has anyone done something and / or it may indicate something, I thank any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need a SMS Service in Android..
it lets you send a SMS to yourself like WhatsApp..
just create confrimation Code and send it Via usual SMS message Intent

Comment: It does not really thought about it, thanks for the tip, I will probably adopt this way of doing :)!